# IEnumerable doest not contain a definition for 'Length'

Tags: c#, linq

```
 error CS1061: 'IEnumerable<Attribute>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Attribute>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have this error using Unity 2018 when i try to compile with .Net instead of IL2CPP
This is the line where i get the error:

```
 if (methods[i].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Length != 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
```

And, in this other method:

```
  var ret = (Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(V), target, method) as V);
```

also, in this method i used methodinfo instead of Delegate. but then ask about no method using 3 values.

Also added "using system.Linq"

Best regards

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `.Count()` or `.Any()` is likely what you want.

Comment: `.Count()` instead of `Length`; or (better) `.Any()` - if any items in the `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: This is because ```IEnumerable``` isn't a length of anything.  It's just an interface with one method ```GetEnumerator()```.  It's commonly confused that the ```IEnumerable``` is an array of some type with a fixed length but this does not have to be and often isn't the case.  ```Array``` and ```List``` do use ```IEnumerable``` interfaces but the interface itself does not imply any items exist.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you want to test if *any* items are in the `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
 if (methods[i].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any())
 {
     continue;
 }
```

If you insist on `Length != 0` approach the right syntax is

```
 if (methods[i].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Count() > 0)
 {
     continue;
 }
```

Comment: @Rahul: Thank you! Technically, `!= 0` and `> 0` are equal in the context; but `> 0` is more readable.

Comment: The first one, ```.Any()``` is recommended as it returns ```true``` as soon as the result is ```true```; which in this case would be any first iteration.  ```Count()``` will enumerate the entirety and return a value to compare against which is much slower.

Comment: It's worth noting that some enumerations don't even contain objects but create them on enumeration which would make ```Count``` and ```Any``` both slow but ```Count``` much slower.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, right now this works fine:

```
 if (methods[i].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Count() > 0)
```

Right now, the other error in:

```
var ret = (Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(V), target, method) as V);
```

I try to use MethodInfo, but isn´t working.
'Delegate' does not contain a definition for 'CreateDelegate'

Comment: That is a sufficiently different question @pacogp - please write a new question rather than discuss it here.